ASP.NET Core MyCouch requests to CouchDB behind Cloudflare are slow locally, but fast in browser and sandbox
Question
I have an ASP.NET Core self-contained application that uses the MyCouch library to make requests to a CouchDB view. The CouchDB instance is protected by Cloudflare. I'm experiencing slow response times when making requests from my local machine, but when I access the same CouchDB view directly from a browser or run the application in a sandbox, the response is fast.
Here are the details:

Environment: I'm running the published version of my ASP.NET Core application locally.
Network: I've tested DNS resolution using nslookup for the CouchDB URL, and the response is fast.
Testing:

If I access the CouchDB view via browser, the response is immediate.
If I run the application in a sandbox, the response is fast.
If I make the request from my local machine, the response is significantly slower, even though the same request is fast on another machine with the same published version.


Configurations tried:

I've set UseProxy = false in my request configuration, but the issue persists.
No proxies are configured on my local machine.
Requests to other services in the same application work as expected.



Additional Information

The CouchDB instance is behind Cloudflare.
I'm wondering if Cloudflare's protection could be affecting the response time for my requests but not the browser or sandbox environment.

Questions

Could Cloudflare's security or caching mechanisms be affecting the requests differently compared to the browser and sandbox environment, and if so, how can I work around this?
What could be causing the slow response specifically for my local machine, and what steps can I take to troubleshoot further?

Any help would be appreciated!
